# Yeast Starter with Corn Sugar?

Tags: yeast, starter

Anyone try making a yeast starter with Corn Sugar instead of DME?  If so what proportions of corn sugar did you use?  I am planning on brewing a high gravity stout, and don't have any DME for the starter, but do have plenty of corn sugar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the starter medium to contain maltose and other nutrients provided by malt, or the yeast that you grow will be poorly suited and/or lose the ability to ferment the maltose in a proper wort.  This is especially true when brewing a high-gravity beer.

Comment: This is largely important due to the nutrients in barley wort that would not be available to the yeast from simple corn sugar.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding yeast nutrient if you have it.

Comment: Yeast nutrient won't provide the maltose the yeast need.